# Raise Java SQLException from SQL Server stored procedure?

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have an SQL Server stored procedure similar to this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc1
(
    @param DECIMAL
)
AS
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO table1 (@param);
        -- further commands
    END;
GO
```

This procedure is called from Java. I introduced a unique constraint on `table1`, on the same column which is inserted above. Is expected to get an SQLException in Java in case of a constraint violation, but it is not happening. When the procedure is executed manually from SSMS, I can see that it prints the constraint violation error, and then continues along the rest of the process, which I think is weird, I expected it to fail. So I changed it like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc1
(
    @param DECIMAL
)
AS
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            INSERT INTO table1 (@param);
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            THROW 51000, 'Unable to insert', 1;
        END CATCH
        -- further commands
    END;
GO
```

Now when I execute it manually in SSMS, the procedure stops in case of a failure, and prints my error message. However the Java calling process is not receiving any indication of the error. How can I propagate this error to the Java calling layer?

UPDATE: Java calling layer:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://x.x.x.x;database=x";

try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, "x", "x")) {
    try (CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall("{call proc1(?)}")) {
        stmt.setInt(1, 1);

        stmt.execute();

        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

At the end, I can see the "Done" message printed to the console.

Comment: I would just use `THROW` here , not `THROW 51000, 'Unable to insert', 1;`, otherwise you hide the error, which makes any debugging really hard in the future.

Comment: You are correct that it makes debugging easier that we can see the exact SQL error. However the Java calling layer is still not notified of the error. It executes the stored procedure, and continues normally. I updated my question with the Java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [`SET NOCOUNT ON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-nocount-transact-sql) as the first statement in the proc to suppress the `DONE_IN_PROC` (rowcount) TDS messages. Otherwise, the code will need to consume all results returned using a `ResultSet` and `getMoreResults` before the error is raised on the client.

Comment: Yes! Thank you. I read about this NOCOUNT flag, but I added it to wrong place, before the SP itself. Now it is working correctly. Thanks!

Comment: @GáborMajor, glad it helped. Also see [The Curious Case of Undetected SQL Exceptions](https://www.dbdelta.com/the-curious-case-of-undetected-sql-exceptions/) for other considerations.